# Add 3 star based score system to Unity2d Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am having difficulties implementing a 3 star based rating system in my 2d game. What I have managed to implement is that when a level is completed, it displays the star rating for that level (1 stars, 2 Stars or 3 Stars) by taking advantage of an integer I stored in PlayerPrefs. Now I want to display the star gotten in the level select screen for each level. Each time a level is finished, it deletes the previous PlayerPrefs that is stored with a new value. And I also want it to only change or display the star in the level select screen only if what you got is larger than what you got before. Very challenging :(

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would look into read/writing to files. Storing each star rating, for each level on a separate line, for example. I wouldn't use PlayerPrefs as they should only really be used for storing a few values, especially if you plan to have many levels. If you want to have some sort of encryption for the file (so it's a little but harder to edit), you could look into converting text files to binary files. But, otherwise look into saving data to files, good luck!.

Comment: I will look into that Luc. I never thought of that